# 'Unalignable boolean Series key provided' while doing selection

Tags: python, pandas

I am just trying to categorize some data with pandas
Basically my data is a string and I want to modify it depending on the value of the X first characters.

I tried this :

```
data['BO In Code'].loc[data['BO In Code'][:2]=='XU']=1
```

> Unalignable boolean Series key provided

This :

```
data['BO In Code'].loc[str(data['BO In Code'])[:2]=='XU']=1
```

and this :

```
data['BO In Code'].loc[data['BO In Code'].index[:2]=='XU']=1
```

gave me :

> 'Cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

Comment: This will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817842/keyerror-when-using-boolean-filter-on-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [**`str`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) string accessor

```
data.loc[data['BO In Code'].str[:2]=='XU', 'BO In Code'] = 1
```

***explanation***

`.loc` for dataframes can take two indexers.  Those indexers can be a single index value, a list of index values, or an array of booleans of equal length as the corresponding dimension being sliced.

In this case, the first indexer is a boolean array where each value is the truth of whether the first 2 characters in the column `'BO In Code'` is equal to `'XU'`.  We use this to filter the rows of the the dataframe.  We still need to specify what column we want.  Happens that we want `'BO In Code'`.

So the first reference to `'BO In Code'` was to find the boolean slice.  The second reference to `'BO In Code'` was to specify the column we wanted. It did not have to be the same column.

Comment: why do I have to put 'BO in Code' again at the end ? isn't it working already without it ?

Comment: Actually when I put it have an index error, and when I don't it is working fine, so i'm gonna get rid of the second one