# KeyError: in pandas when trying to change boolean column values into string while using .loc method

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am running a conditional loop to create a new column in my DataFrame (TDF) based on the value of column "alone". 
If the value is 0, add the string "alone" else add "with family" in the column "alone". 
I am using the code:
I am getting the error:

```
tdf['alone'].loc[['alone'] >0]= 'with family'
tdf['alone'].loc[['alone'] ==0] = 'alone'
```

After running the above line, I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

I referred this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817842/keyerror-when-using-boolean-filter-on-pandas-data-frame), and what I gathered is that I need to have `row_indexer` in `tdf['alone'].loc[[row_indexer,['alone']] = 'alone'` but I am not sure how to get the values in `row_indexer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` and boolean masks - compare column of `DataFrame` with value `0`, not one item list `[alone]`:

```
tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] > 0, 'alone'] = 'with family'
tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] ==0, 'alone'] = 'alone'
```

If not negative numbers is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
tdf['alone'] = np.where(tdf['alone'] == 0,  'alone', 'with family')
```

**Sample**:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'alone':[4,4,5,0,5,0],
                   'col':[1,1,9,4,2,3]})

print (tdf)
   alone  col
0      4    1
1      4    1
2      5    9
3      0    4
4      5    2
5      0    3

tdf['alone'] = np.where(tdf['alone'] == 0,  'alone', 'with family')
print (tdf)

         alone  col
0  with family    1
1  with family    1
2  with family    9
3        alone    4
4  with family    2
5        alone    3
```

Also solution is wrong, because [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21463854/2901002) -  it could create a copy which updates a copy of `tdf['alone']` which you would not see:

```
#added boolean mask tdf['alone'] > 0
tdf['alone'].loc[tdf['alone'] > 0 ]= 'with family'
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the fast reply and your suggested method work flawlessly, but i am curious how can i do it my way? Do you have any say or suggestions on that?

Comment: @Sajal - Then use `tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] > 0, 'alone'] = 'with family'` and `tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] ==0, 'alone'] = 'alone'`

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.Series.clip`

clip values to be only `0` and `1` and use it to slice an array

```
tdf.assign(alone=np.array(['alone', 'with family'])[tdf.alone.clip(0, 1)])

         alone  col
0  with family    1
1  with family    1
2  with family    9
3        alone    4
4  with family    2
5        alone    3
```

---

#### `pandas.Series.map`

```
tdf.assign(alone=tdf.alone.map(lambda x: 'with family' if x else 'alone'))

         alone  col
0  with family    1
1  with family    1
2  with family    9
3        alone    4
4  with family    2
5        alone    3
```

---

#### `map`

Version 2

```
tdf.assign(alone=tdf.alone.map(lambda x: {0: 'alone'}.get(x, 'with family')))

         alone  col
0  with family    1
1  with family    1
2  with family    9
3        alone    4
4  with family    2
5        alone    3
```

---

#### Setup

Borrowed from @jezrael

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'alone':[4,4,5,0,5,0],
                   'col':[1,1,9,4,2,3]})
```

Answer (score 0):

`[['alone'] > 0]` compares the Python list `['alone']` to the integer `0`. Use the following instead:

```
tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] > 0, 'alone'] = 'with family'
tdf.loc[tdf['alone'] == 0, 'alone'] = 'alone'
```

Comment: Please dont change your solution by me :(

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, when i ran your code, it replaces the whole row of the data frame tdf(890X14) with the "alone/ with family" according to the column "alone", whereas i only want to change the values of the column "alone".

Comment: @jezrael I did not change my solution "by you". Please don't edit my answer in contradiction with my intent. I made an error and corrected it, you just happened to also answer correctly.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy - So sorry, it is impossible verify. Maybe I was wrong :(